# Sequelize - .update - setTags is not a function

Tags: javascript, api, express, orm, sequelize.js

### "setTags is not a function"

I have Many-to-Many relationships for Posts and Tags.

```
db.tag.belongsToMany(db.post, {
  through: 'post_tags',
  foreignKey: 'tagId',
  otherKey: 'postId',
})
db.post.belongsToMany(db.tag, {
  through: 'post_tags',
  foreignKey: 'postId',
  otherKey: 'tagId',
})
```

I'm trying to update the Post's content, including the associated Tags.

---

This beginning at line 7:

- Check for tags
- Match found tags
- Set the tags of post

---

```
exports.update = (req, res) => {
      const id = req.params.id
      Post.update(req.body, {
        where: { id: id },
      })
        .then((number) => {
          if (req.body.tags) {
            Tag.findAll({
              where: {
                name: {
                  [Op.or]: req.body.tags,
                },
              },
            }).then((tag_items) => {
              res.setTags(tag_items)
            })
          }
          if (number == 1) {
            res.send({
              message: 'This post attempt was successful.',
            })
          } else {
            res.send({
              message: `Problem with updating id=${id}. May not exist, or req.body could be empty!`,
            })
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          res.status(500).send({
            message: 'There was an error updating post id=' + id,
          })
        })
    }
```

---

I use something very similar for creating a Post.

I was hoping this would work like how it does for that.

I have read so much of the documents and online searches.

At this point I feel like it must be something simple I'm overlooking.

Maybe even a misspelling, or bad positioning of something.

---

I have tried creating response data with findByPk as the Post.

Then running this with setTags, I still get the same error.

Not sure if maybe because Post.update returns different data?

Than doing Post.create, I thought I read something on this.

But I had tried adding another parameter and wasn't getting expected results.

---

If you can offer any advice, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You called `setTags` in `res` which is not a Sequeize model of `Post`.
You need to get `Post` instance first like this:

```js
 Post.findOne({
        where: { id: id },
      }).then((post) => {
if (req.body.tags) {
            Tag.findAll({
              where: {
                name: {
                  [Op.or]: req.body.tags,
                },
              },
            }).then((tag_items) => {
              post.setTags(tag_items)
            })
          }  
})
```

And I recommend to use `async/await` to have straint-forward code instead of chain of `then` in this case:

```js
exports.update = async (req, res) => {
      const id = req.params.id
   try {
      const number = await Post.update(req.body, {
        where: { id: id },
      })
      if (req.body.tags) {
        const post = await Post.findOne({
          where: { id: id },
        })
        const tag_items = await Tag.findAll({
           where: {
             name: {
               [Op.or]: req.body.tags,
             },
          });
          post.setTags(tag_items)
      }
      if (number == 1) {
         res.send({
           message: 'This post attempt was successful.',
         })
      } else {
         res.send({
           message: `Problem with updating id=${id}. May not exist, or req.body could be empty!`,
         })
      }
  } catch((err) {
       res.status(500).send({
         message: 'There was an error updating post id=' + id,
       })
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for pointing that out. I should have noticed, but I guess was referencing the create method I have too much and got mixed up on this part. The async/await is also a great suggestion, and I'm going to start working with it more often going forward. This actually solved my issues and I'm pretty sure I have a much better understanding on a few things now. I really appreciate the help, thanks again!